# Not able to parse Javascript object using literal

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

My Code is like below

```
import APPLICATION_PROVIDER_FIRSTNAME_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Application__c.Provider__r.FirstName__c';

var result =[{"CAPR__Provider__r":{"Name":"flow 4","CAPR__FirstName__c":"Aksh"}}];
```

I am getting output if I hard code like this

```
let firstName=result[0].CAPR__Provider__r.CAPR__FirstName__c;
```

but if I put like below I am getting undefined only

```
let firstName=result[0][APPLICATION_PROVIDER_FIRSTNAME_FIELD.fieldApiName]
```

where

```
APPLICATION_PROVIDER_FIRSTNAME_FIELD.fieldApiName returns CAPR__Provider__r.CAPR__FirstName__c
```

Need help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not get object nested property with path separated by `.`

But you do it with `split` and `reduce` method to simplify access any nested level.

```js
var result = [
  { CAPR__Provider__r: { Name: "flow 4", CAPR__FirstName__c: "Aksh" } },
];

const path = "CAPR__Provider__r.CAPR__FirstName__c";

const first = path.split(".").reduce((acc, key) => acc[key], result[0]);

console.log(first);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the string

```js
const result = [{
  "CAPR__Provider__r": {
    "Name": "flow 4",
    "CAPR__FirstName__c": "Aksh"
  }
}];
const fieldApiName = 'CAPR__Provider__r.CAPR__FirstName__c';
const [providerKey, firstnameKey] = fieldApiName.split(".")

let firstName = result[0][providerKey][firstnameKey]

console.log(firstName)
```